# Adapter from USB C device to USB port

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

Adapters for USB devices to the new USB C ports on MacBooks are well-known. But what about the reverse?

I am currently thinking about using a MacBook Pro 15", which has only USB ports. In case I had to use an USB C device, would it be possible for me to find anything to connect it to my USB ports?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a USB-A to USB-C cable.

Example: [3.1 USB-A to USB-C™ Cable (Also Known as USB Type-C™)](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F2CU029/)  from Belkin

It's $29.99 USD, however I'm sure you can use a search engine to find a better deal, e.g.:

- [Google search - 3.1 USB-A to USB-C cable](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=3.1%20USB-A%20to%20USB-C%20cable&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)
- [Google search - 2.0 USB-A to USB-C cable](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=2.0%20USB-A%20to%20USB-C%20cable&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)